# Does Codeception BDD have a @Transform function like Behat does?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, codeception, behat

In Behat you can do a transformation like so:

```php
<?php

/**
 * @Transform /^"([^"]+)" shipping method$/
 * @Transform /^shipping method "([^"]+)"$/
 * @Transform :shippingMethod
 */
public function getShippingMethodByName($shippingMethodName)
{
    $shippingMethod = $this->shippingMethodRepository->findOneByName($shippingMethodName);

    Assert::notNull(
        $shippingMethod,
        sprintf('Shipping method with name "%s" does not exist', $shippingMethodName)
    );

    return $shippingMethod;
}

/**
 * @Given /^(shipping method "[^"]+") belongs to ("[^"]+" tax category)$/
 */
public function shippingMethodBelongsToTaxCategory(
    ShippingMethodInterface $shippingMethod,
    TaxCategoryInterface $taxCategory
) {
    // some logic here
}
```

Basically, adding a colon before a variable and using `@Transform` keyword.

Is there a way to do that in [Codeception](https://codeception.com/docs/BDD)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

codeception, despite using behat vendor libraries, does not  implement the `@Transform` feature.